# Limit of sum of sine terms

Tags: limits

Given $$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+\dots+f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-kf(0)\right]$$ where $k$ is a positive integer and $f(x)=\sin(x)$. How to find $L$?

Comment: For fixed $k$, and $i\le k$, and $n$ large, we have $\sin(i/n)=i/n +O(1/n^3)$.

Comment: Thanks André is this the correct solution $frac{k(k+1)}{2}$ is taking $lim_{n \to \infty} n f(\frac{i}{n})-f(0))=i.f'(0)$ is incorrect?

Comment: For sine I think we get $\frac{k(k+1)}{2}$, but have not written out the calculation.

Comment: Please tell about the another doubt I asked in the comment

Comment: If the function is differentiable at  $0$ we get $if'(0)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty} n\left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)+\dots+f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)-kf(0)\right]$$
then
$$L=\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{f\left(h\right)+f\left(2h\right)+\dots+f\left(kh\right)-kf(0)}{h}\right]$$
then
$$L=\lim_{h\to 0} \left[\frac{(f\left(h\right)-f(0))+(f\left(2h\right)-f(0))+\dots+(f\left(kh\right)-f(0))}{h}\right]$$
then
$$L=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f\left(h\right)-f(0)}{h}+2\frac{f\left(2h\right)-f(0)}{2h}+\dots+k\frac{f\left(kh\right)-f(0)}{kh}$$
then
$$L=f'(0) + 2f'(0) + \dots + kf'(0)$$
then
$$L = \frac{k(k+1)}{2} f'(0)$$

Finally: the asked question is particular case of this solution. Since $f(x) = \sin x$ is derivable in neighbourhood of $x=0$ we have $f'(x=0) = \cos 0 = 1$ so
$$
L = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you consider just the limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,(f(i/n)-f(0))$$ for a $C^1$ function $f$ and fixed $i$? What happens if we take a finite sum of such limits?

Comment: +1, but you omitted the $n$ term that multiplies the difference term.  Otherwise, the limit would be zero for continuous functions.

Comment: @Dr.MV of course, thanks for the catch.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  - Mark

Answer (score 0):

We have: $f(0) = \sin (0) = 0, \displaystyle n\cdot \sum_{i=1}^k f\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)=n\cdot \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^k \sin\left(\dfrac{i}{n}\right)=n\cdot \dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)-\cos\left(\dfrac{2k+1}{2n}\right)}{2\sin \left(\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{2k+2}{4n}\right)}{\dfrac{2k+2}{4n}}\cdot \dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{2k}{4n}\right)}{\dfrac{2k}{4n}}}{\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{n}}}\cdot \dfrac{k(k+1)}{4}\Rightarrow L = \dfrac{k(k+1)}{4}$

Comment: How do you get that summation of sin(i/n) in terms of cosine, I really don't get it.

Comment: @Abomm: You can look it up by typing: $\sin x + \sin(2x) + \cdots + \sin(kx)$, and you get dozen web sites in google. Try it.